# Parse JSON to mysql with Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I try to seed JSON into MySQL via Laravel. I managed to do it with simple JSON files but now I face this challenge with different and most complicated JSON format.

JSON Arrays

```
{
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
```

and JSON Arrays of objects

Thank you

Comment: If you need the corrosponding structure you could try this: https://sqlizer.io/#/ However you should design a good database yourself as such tools are very limited.

Comment: i tried, can't work with advanced json...

Comment: have u created any table structure already?

Comment: yes, my table is ok, the problem is how to parse json arrays of strings and json arrays of objects via php .

Comment: `json_decode` plus some `foreach` logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a JSON string and convert it to a PHP array you should use PHP's built in json_decode() function.  Since you are using an associative array, use it in the following way:

```
$json = 'JSON string';

$object = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now, you may call keys and display values:

```
$name = $object['name'] // John
$cars = $object['cars'] //['Ford', 'BMW', 'Fiat']
$ford = $object['cars'][0] // Ford
```

Now that your information is stored in a PHP array, you can use Eloquent with the array's nested values:

**Using Eloquent:**

```
Object::create([
    'name' => $object['name'],
    //
])->save();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Luke, until this point I was too. I don't know how to handle the array, for example above, cars

Comment: See updated answer :) you would access it as you would any array, except now you are treating $object['cars'] as the array.